# Transform $a\mathbf x+\mathbf b$, then make it $k$-sparse, resulting least modification?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, sparse-matrices

Consider vector $\mathbf x = (x_1,x_2,\cdots,x_n)$, $a$ a scalar, $\mathbf b = (b_0,\cdots,b_0)$ and $k < n$.

I want to transform $\mathbf x$ ($\mathbf y = a\mathbf x+\mathbf b$) such that if I set $k$ elements of the resulting vector ($\mathbf y$) to zero, it is modified as less as possible.

Or equivalently, what is the best transformation of type $\mathbf y=a\mathbf x+\mathbf b$ such that, projecting $\mathbf y$ into $k$-sparse vectors, leads to minimum change (in $\ell$-2 norm sense)? (Also what values of $\mathbf y$ are set to zero?)

Edit: Actually, this problem arouse from this original problem:
Find $k$-sparse vector $\mathbf x \in \mathbb R_+^n$ which its periodic auto-correlation function (PACF) has constant sidelobes i.e. $c_1=c_2=\cdots=c_n$, where $c_n = \sum_m \tilde x_{n+m}\tilde x_m$.

One way to numerically do this is minimizing $\sum_{l=1}^{n-1}(c_l-c_{l+1})^2$ (without considering sparsity constraint) and finding a non-sparse $\mathbf x$ , then making it $k$-sparse using the transform stated in the question (since the property of constant sidelobes is preserved under this transform).
So I'm looking for the best transform of this kind.

Comment: "modified as little as possible" in what norm? in the absolute or in the relative sense? Can you be more precise about this?

Comment: @fedja in $\ell$-2 norm or euclidean distance, thanks

Comment: I believe this is NP-hard.

Comment: @Igor Rivin Anything wrong with my solution, then?

Comment: @fedja either with your solution or with my belief system :) I will ponder.

Answer (score 1):

I'll use $a$ instead of $\mathbf x$ and $t$ instead of $a$. Formally, the problem asks to find $t$ and a subset $S$ of cardinality $k$ such that $\sum_{j\in S}(a_jt+b_j)^2$ is as small as possible. Of course, once you know the set, finding $t$ is not a problem. Also, if you know the ordering of $2n$ numbers $\pm(a_jt+b_j)$, finding $S$ is not a problem either. Now the point is that when $t$ moves from $-\infty$ to $\infty$, there are at most $2n^2$ changes of order (some 2 lines have to intersect for that), so you can list all these orders, choose the set corresponding to each order, do the trivial minimization of the quadratics for each set, and, finally, choose the least of $2n^2$ values.

If you do it intelligently, the running time is $Cn^2\log n$ because each crossing takes just constant time to update all relevant values if you sort the crossing points before starting (that's where $\log$ comes from).

Comment: Thank you for your great contribution. You know, $\mathbf b = (b_0,\cdots,b_0)$ is a part of transformation to be found, and it is not a constant. I edited the question to make it clearer.

Comment: It makes no sense now: $a=b_0=0$ is an obvious answer.

Comment: Drop this obvious solution, since it is out of interest. Thanks

Comment: Look, then I will say $a=b_0=\epsilon$ where $\epsilon$ is the machine precision. Mathematics can help to solve your problem only if the problem is posed in a sensible way. The initial one was, the new one isn't. Try to think a bit of what you really need.

Comment: I think it is better to state the original problem which have given arise to this problem. Please look at the edit to the question.

Comment: Not sure I can follow it as it is written :(. What is given? What can be changed? What are the exact constraints? What is the objective function? If anyone (whether the OP or not) can clearly answer these 4 questions, I'm ready to give it a serious thought. Right now I'm just a bit confused...

Comment: I edited the question to answer your questions. But let me answer them here too. 

1. $(n,k)$ is given. 

2. I can't understand your question. 

3. Solution must be $k$-sparse and positive-valued 

4. In order to satisfy the constant sidelobes property we should minimize $\sum_{l=1}^{n-1}(c_l-c_{l+1})^2$ s.t. $\mathbf x$ is $k$-sparse.

Comment: OK, I'll try to think of the "original problem" then rather than  of the "numeric approach". You need just one vector $x$, right?

Comment: Thanks for your attention. Yes I need the optimal $k$-sparse $\mathbf x$ (i.e. $\mathbf x$ with minimum $\sum_{l=1}^{n-1}(c_l-c_{l+1})^2$)

Comment: Last question: is there any real reason to prefer the particular sum mentioned to, say, $\sum_{0<k,m<n}(c_k-c_m)^2$?

Comment: No, there isn't. I chose that, since I thought it is the best function representing the constant sidelobes property.